# On hover only back image enlarge not overlapped image

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have two images where coloured image is overlapped by Gray image looks like below third image. Is it possible that hover on third image only coloured image will scale to enlarge but not Gray image? I expect zoom effect through lens. Please check below my html and css code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

CSS

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
.slide img {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.slide img:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.slide span img {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
.slide span img:hover {transform: scale(1);}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slide">
    <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="photo" />
    <span><img src="images/lense.png" alt="photo" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about having only one image in the `.slide` div and forget about the repetitive `span` in the html markup? I suppose you will want to apply that lens effect on more than one image.

Having the grey image as an `:after` pseudo-element will ease your markup.

The `overflow: hidden` will prevent the scaled image to be visible all around the grey image. And the `display: inline-block;` just auto size the div, instead of having it 100% width by default.

The `float: right;` on `.slide img` is to prevent a small space at the bottom where the scaled image would still be visible due to some space occupied by the `:after` pseudo-element.

Then, hovering `.slide`, the `.slide:hover img` applies on the image (not on `.slide`)

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide img{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 0.4s;
  float: right;
}
.slide:after{
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t6LE.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.slide:hover img{
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9nR4.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your .slide img and .slide img:hover rules apply to both the photo and the lens images.  You need a rule that targets just the photo image to apply the zoom.

Also, because the lens image is covering the photo image, you won't get a hover on the photo.  One way to address this is to apply the hover modifier to the div part of the selector

```css
.slide {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.slide > img {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.slide span img {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
}
.slide:hover > img {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9nR4.jpg" alt="photo" />
  <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t6LE.png" alt="photo" /></span>
</div>
```